# "start", referenced from: -u command line option ld: symbol(s) not found

Tags: linker, ld

I try to build an example from the book "hacking and securing iOS Applications" by Jonathan Zdziarski, compiling an example with a lot of object-files created. but when compiling the binary with:

```
export PLATFORM=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform
$PLATFORM/Developer/usr/bin/arm-apple-darwin10-llvm-gcc-4.2 -o launchd launchd.o syscalls.o -static -nostartfiles -nodefaultlibs -nostdlib -W1,-e,_main
```

the terminal says: 
`Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
  "start", referenced from:
     -u command line option
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status`

Normally, this message shows up, when libraries are missing, but how can i find out, which one? I'm pretty sure, there's no problem with the source code.

Answer (score 1):

-arch armv7 -isysroot -L$(SDK)  -L$(SDK)/usr/lib/system